# How to read a space in bash - read will not

Tags: bash, character, whitespace

Many people have shown how to keep spaces when reading a line in bash.  But I have a character based algorithm which need to process each end every character separately - spaces included. Unfortunately I am unable to get bash read to read a  *single* space character from input.

`while read -r -n 1 c; do
        printf "[%c]" "$c"
done <<< "mark spitz"
printf "[ ]\n"`

yields

`[m][a][r][k][][s][p][i][t][z][][ ]`

I've hacked my way around this, but it would be nice to figure out how to read a single *any* single character.
Yep, tried setting IFS, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the input field separator<sup>(a)</sup> so that it doesn't treat space (or any character) as a delimiter, that works just fine:

```
printf 'mark spitz' | while IFS="" read -r -n 1 c; do
    printf "[%c]" "$c"
done
echo
```

That gives you:

```
[m][a][r][k][ ][s][p][i][t][z]
```

You'll notice I've also slightly changed how you're getting the input there, `<<<` appears to provide a extraneous character at the end and, while it's not important to the input method itself, I though it best to change that to avoid any confusion.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, I'm aware that you *said* you've tried setting `IFS` but, since you didn't actually show *how* you'd tried this, and it appears to work fine the way I do it, I have to assume you may have just done something wrong.

Comment: Wow.  I must have had a second issue with not quoting a variable in assignment or output (whitespace is my bash nemesis), and when I tried this fix, it failed because of a the second issue. Shows the value of reducing tests to bare minimum - rather than trying the fix in your large program!

Comment: BTW using the `while read do done <<<  "input"` is important because I stay in the same shell, and have access to the shell namespace.  Your `printf "input" | while do done` spawns a subshell which has as different namespace and can't easily move data back and forth between the do block and the calling parent shell.